# EdgeCollider2D for a ParticleSystem in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am just stuck at a very simple problem i guess :)
I want to draw a edge collider like the black line show in the picture below. The Problem is that i only can move the collider to the left or the right, but not up or down. Is there a shortcut or something that can help me??

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question but about Unity Editor user interface. This question would be more suitable on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com